# Prepared statement with and without "on duplicate key update"

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to remove this ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE because I would like to have duplicates.  This statement does work and inserts data but not duplicates. Please help.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO projectselect (id_proj, project, role, id_agent)
VALUES ( ?,?,?, ( select idagency FROM agentsInfo WHERE email = ?))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`id_agent` = VALUES(`id_agent`),
`project` = VALUES(`project`),
`role` = VALUES(`role`)
";

if (($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) === false) {
trigger_error($con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$result2= mysqli_query($con, $idq);

$row_number = 1;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

$id_proj= $row["id_proj"];
$project= $row["project"];
$role= $row["role"];
$id_proj++;

}


if ($stmt->bind_param("ssss",
$id_proj,
$postproj,
$postrole,
$_SESSION["email"]) === false) {
trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);

}


if (($stmt->execute()) === false) {
trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: You're using `mysqli_prepare()` on one query, but then using `mysqli_query()` with a different query. This won't work in the form you have it. You probably also need to remove any `UNIQUE` indexes on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is only triggered when the insertion of a record conflicts with existing ones, and this conflict will only happen when your table has "unique" fields -- fields which the value can only exist once among all records of that table.

First thing you have to fix is to remove `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY` keys and indexes from your table. Once it is done, the whole thing should work already.

You can then remove the `ON DUPLICATE KEY...` statement from your query once it is no longer relevant, to keep your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow duplicates, remove the `unique index` from the table `projectselect`.